# Specify which Publish script to use on build?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

How do I have SSDT run my publish script when I build my solution file?

If you:
1) Right click on your solution
2) Click Configration Properties
3) Click Configuration

I can see the database project and where it is checked to deploy on build, it does not let me specify what publish script to use.

Comment: Are you trying to use publish profiles? Pre/Post Deploy scripts? Want to make sure I understand so you get the answer you need.

Comment: One way of sorting that out is to use the SqlPackage utility in the Post-Build Event Command Line box. Not sure if the best, but couldn't find anything else. Just blogged about it:
http://tangodude.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/ssdt-publish-on-build-using-specific-profile/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible out of the box.

**Why**? They are two very different things.

**Building** (if you were to think of it as code) compiles and checks, producing artefacts. For .NET code those artefacts are DLL's/.exe etc. For .sqlproj it's the .dacpac etc that turn up in /sql/[Build Configuration Name].

**Publishing** is akin to Deploying if you were talking .NET code. Building won't include Publishing as an action.

Ironically, a Publish action *also Builds the solution*, so my suggestion would instead be to consider one of the following:

1. Publish the project (right click Publish, or double click your chosen .publish.xml file) whenever you want to build.
2. Use the [Post-Build command line in the project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833259(v=vs.100).aspx) to call [sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) to deploy your newly compiled .dacpac with your specified .publish.xml profile - but note that this will also impact your use of the Publish action from within Visual Studio as a Publish *builds* and then *publishes* (so you'd end up publishing twice).
3. Depending on your comfort levels/if you are a command-line fan, then use the command line (bash file? Powershell?) to [call msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) followed by sqlpackage.exe. Whenever you want to build, run your command in cmd.exe.
4. Similar to #3, [add a menu item to the Tools menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164725.aspx) that would do exactly the same thing (msbuild followed by sqlpackage deployment) but from within Visual Studio itself.
5. Look at a Continuous Integration model (TFS/TeamCity/Bamboo/Jenkins and about 3000-others), which could build and deploy for you automatically with every change - either on another server, or running locally (I put this in without knowing your scenario, so may be very much unsuitable to solve your problem).